# How to dynamically replace one set of server controls with another in asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on asp.net webforms. I have a usercontrol which has several server controls. There are three related dropdown boxes. If there are multiple values on all these dropdown boxes, I have to let the user choose values from them and then I save them in database. If each one of them has only one value, then I have to show the values as read only - say as asp.net labels. These values also need to be saved in the database. Please let me know how to replace one set of controls with another and get their values.

Thanks

Comment: You can display drop downs as read only without making them labels - would this fulfill your requirement?

Comment: Unfortunately no! The users say they can't read through the greyed out controls :(

Answer (score 1):

So to show one set of controls over the other, consider the following HTML:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="List1" runat="server" Visible="false" />
<asp:DropDownList ID="List2" runat="server" Visible="false" />
<asp:DropDownList ID="List3" runat="server" Visible="false" />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Visible="false" />
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Visible="false" />
<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Visible="false" />
```

if you want the drop down lists visible then run this in the code-behind where relevant:

```
List1.Visible = true;
List2.Visible = true;
List3.Visible = true;
```

and in contrast, if you want the labels visible then run this code:

```
Label1.Visible = true;
Label2.Visible = true;
Label3.Visible = true;
```

Please note that when a control in ASP.NET is **not** visible - it's **not** rendered. So the control is **not** included in the HTML. This is why I set ***all of them*** to invisible to start with.